# why can't I select inputs by class with jQuery serializeArray?

Tags: serialization, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to post different columns of a table with jQuery's ajax functionality...

This works for me: `var fields = $(":input").serializeArray();`

This attempt at a reduced set does not: `var fields = $('input.ebtcf').serializeArray();`

I've gotten pretty handy with jQuery selectors, so why my second case doesn't work confuses me.

Any thoughts?

Thanks, Lille

Comment: Can you post your relevant html?

Comment: Sure they are `input` elements and not `select` or `textarea` elements ? because `:input` targets all those.

Comment: Is it possible that the selected elements are disabled or do not contain a name attribute?

Answer (score 1):

My apologies: the problem was that the input fields I was attempting to serialize in the above manner were disabled.

Case closed!

Lille